# Powershell - initialize class file from Terminal

Tags: powershell

I have Powershell class defined in ps1 file.

In main.ps1 i initialized that class

```
$class = [myClass]::new()
```

When,in Powershell ISE i open file and click [[image: Run script (F5)[1]] for both class.ps1 and main.ps1 all works fine. 
When i close PowerShell ISE, and open classic Powershell terminal (As Administrator), and execute

```
.folder\class.ps1
.\main.ps1
```

Then i'm getting following error after executing `.\main.p1` from terminal

```
Unable to find type [myClass].
```

So how, from Powershell terminal, to initialize file with my class, without running Powershell ISE ?

Comment: Load the class using the '.' operation first  . .\folder\class.ps1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a file in Powershell is done with the `.` operator.

```
. .\folder\class.ps1
```